# Mapping: Table contains physical column name referred to by multiple logical column names

Tags: hibernate, many-to-one, composite-key

I have 3 classes - Issue, Sprint and EmbeddableId class SprintId.

I don't know how to achieve having `jiraInstance` field both in `Issue` and `Sprint` class. As `Issue` may not be connected to any `Sprint` I want to have `jiraInstance` java field on `Issue` to track in which jira instance this particular issue was created. When its connected to `Sprint` I want to just have `jiraInstance` as part of its composite key. But below mapping gives me:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [issue] contains physical column name [jira_instance] referred to by multiple logical column names: [jira_instance], [jiraInstance]
```

classes:

```
class Issue {
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "sprint_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "sprint_id"),
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "jira_instance",
                    referencedColumnName = "jira_instance")
    })
    private Sprint lastSprint;

    //this field causes clash with 'jira_instance' in @JoinColumn
    private String jiraInstance;
}

class Sprint {
    @EmbeddedId
    private SprintId id;
}
class SprintId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "sprint_id")
    private String sprintId;

    @Column(name = "jira_instance")
    private String jiraInstance;
}
```

Adding @Column as:

```
@Column(name="jira_instance")
private String jiraInstance;
```

cause hibernate to claim that it has to be `insertable = true, updatable = false`, but I need to be able to add jiraInstance to `Issue` when its not connected to any sprint.

Answer (score 4):

To clarify - as there is no marked answer to this issue yet:

When you use a named column reference in any way on one class field, make sure **ALL** references use the exact same name. Especially when they are differently named (`jira_instance` vs. `jiraInstance`, in your example).

The following example should work:

```
class Issue {
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "sprint_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "sprint_id"),
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "jira_instance",
                    referencedColumnName = "jira_instance") // make sure you use the same name
    })
    private Sprint lastSprint;

    @Column(name = "jira_instance") // make sure you use the same name
    private String jiraInstance;
}

class Sprint {
    @EmbeddedId
    private SprintId id;
}
class SprintId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "sprint_id")
    private String sprintId;

    @Column(name = "jira_instance") // make sure you use the same name
    private String jiraInstance;
}
```

This means: `insertable = false, updatable = false` is not necessary to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that only one property/field can be used for writing a column, otherwise there could be conflicts. Use the following mapping:

```
class Issue {
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "sprint_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "sprint_id"),
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "jira_instance",
                    referencedColumnName = "jira_instance", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Sprint lastSprint;

    private String jiraInstance;
}
```

You just have to make sure that when you set `lastSprint`, you also set `jiraInstance` to the value of `Sprint#jiraInstance`